# How to "Add an App Engine Module" to Android Studio when the wizard freezes

Tags: android, google-app-engine, freeze

I was following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/add_module), and these were the first steps I was following:

> Start Android Studio and open the project for the Android app that
>   needs the new backend.
>
> Right-click on your project and select New > Module.
>
> Select Google Cloud Module from the list, then click Next :
>
> Choose backend module Select the desired backend type; for example
>   choose App Engine Java Endpoints Module, and then supply the remaining
>   information in the New Google Cloud Module form:
>
> Enter module parameters Supply a module name for your backend; this
>   name will be displayed and used in your Android Studio project.
>
> Supply a package name. This package name will be used for all classes
>   imported from this template.
>
> Select the client module (containing your Android app) in this
>   project. This module will be automatically set up to have the right
>   compile and build dependencies to be able to call your newly generated
>   backend.
>
> Click Finish to generate the new backend.

but when I got to the last step ("Click Finish to generate the new backend") and clicked "Finish," Android Studio froze and I had to force-quit. I relaunched Android Studio, did the same thing, and it froze again.

So, **how can I use the Google App Engine for a free server to store a large database for my app**? Is there any other way besides following that tutorial that freezes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. An update to the latest version of Android Studio solved the problem of freezing for me. (I have now the verison Android Studio 1.3 / Build number 141.2024585)

An other way to create an Google App Engine Endpoints Project is by using Maven:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/helloendpoints

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) download sdk to your local. After that, in Android studio, click **File**->**Settings**->**Plugins**->**Install Plugins from Disk**. Hope this can solve your problem.